# Why is a current source needed for the interlock loop in an electric vehicle?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am planning to use HVIL for an electric vehicle. When I searched for it, I found a diagram in Tesla's *HVIL Diagnostic
Guide*. They use a current source to check whether the interlock loop is open or not.

Is there any reason to specifically need a current source to check this, or can I check the interlock loop using just a voltage source?

[image: Tesla interlock loop diagram]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intent is that the interlock works reliably irrespective of the number of elements in the loop.  Specifying a current source automatically adapts the voltage to the number of elements, whereas a voltage source would have to be tuned to the number of elements (effectively becoming a current source!).

You can also use the actual voltage to check the number of elements in the loop, and ensure there isn't a short.

Comment: Can't you do the reverse by having a voltage source and checking the actual current?

Comment: You could, but with a constant current source you get equal voltage steps for each unit on the path, whilst for a voltage source, the steps get smaller and smaller for each unit you add.  If you have circuitry in each unit to check the loop state, the constant current approach gives a stable threshold irrespective of the number of units.